lower bounding $\Big\{\Big(\sum_{i\in[n]}\sum_{j\in[n]}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Big)^2-{\sum_{i\in[n]}(\sum_{j\in[n]}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2}\Big\}$
Consider
$$S(\theta):=\Big\{\Big(\sum_{i\in[n]}\sum_{j\in[n]}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Big)^2-{\sum_{i\in[n]}(\sum_{j\in[n]}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2}\Big\}$$
Motivation.
I am curious about the minimum value of $S(\theta)$, and the larger (in the sense that it is a growing function on $n$), the better.
In fact, if we do not add any constraint on $\theta$, the minimum value of $S$ is zero.
Specifically, the $\inf_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]^n}S(\theta)=0$, attained at the following case (2), i.e., the angles $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n$ form a regular polygon in the unit circle. For example, the figure in case (2) is $\theta=[0,\pi/3,2\pi/3,3\pi/3,4\pi/3,5\pi/3]$ forming a regular $6$-gon.
In order to achieve the goal $\inf_{\theta\in Q}S(\theta)$, we must need to exclude $6$-gon.
Motivated from above, my question can be said as:
finding a region $Q$ of $\theta$, such that $\inf_{\theta\in Q}S(\theta)$ is large, in the sense that it is an increasing function of $n$.
A reformulation might be helpful.
Reformulate $\theta_i$ as $v_i=:=(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$, above is equivalent to $$(\sum_{i\in[n]}\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2-\sum_{i\in[n]}(\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2$$
Denote matrix $P$ where $P_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j \rangle$.
The first term $\sum_{i\in[n]}(\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2$ is $\sum_i(\sum_j P_{ij})^2$.
The second term $(\sum_{i\in[n]}\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2=(\sum_i\sum_j P_{ij})^2=(\sum_iv_i)^2$.
From this reformulation, it is not hard to obtain $(\sum_{i\in[n]}\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2\geq \sum_{i\in[n]}(\sum_{j\in[n]}\langle v_i,v_j \rangle)^2$, where equality is attaned at the following case (2).
special $\theta$
(1) $\theta$ a vectors containing elements that are all equal.

In this case, $\sum_i(\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2=n^3$ and $(\sum_i\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2=n^4$
(2) $\theta$ forms a regular $n$-gon.

In this case, $\sum_i(\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2=(\sum_i\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2=0$. To see this, we can write each $\theta_i$ as a vector $v_i:=(\cos\theta_i,\sin\theta_i)$. It is clear that $\sum_j\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)=\sum_j\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=0$, and the conclusion can be followed.

$\theta\neq \textrm{regular polygon}$ - does this mean ${\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n}$ is not equal to the set of angles of a regular n-gon or they are not all equal to $\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$ ?
I think your post would benefit from removing some clutters/making some terms more standard. Right now, it's not very simple to read.

in any case, your first summand is:
$$\sum_{i,j}(\cos\theta_i\cos\theta_j + \sin\theta_i\sin\theta_j) = (\sum_i\cos\theta_i)^2 + (\sum_i\sin\theta_i)^2$$
and there might be a similar simplification for the second summand.

@dezdichado It means that $\theta$ is not the set of angles of a regular $n$-gon. I just edited the post, thanks!
